# Using React Native with Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

So I'm trying redux with react, I keep getting this error in the emulator

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
```

and

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. 

ExceptionsManager.js:63Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
```

I've isolated the problem down to this

```
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
```

When I remove the provider the contents of App render (let's just say they're a simple 'Hello World' Text component). When I put it back in, it does not.

I know that in an older version of react this was a problem, but I'm on `15.4.0`.

But just in case, I tried doing something like this

```
// wrapper.js
const wrapper = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      {() => <App />}
    </Provider>
  );
}

// index

AppRegistry.registerComponent('BasketballAndroidFrontend', () => wrapper);
```

How do I get around this? Have I even diagnosed this correctly?

Comment: How are the components imported?

Comment: `{() => <App />}` is just an anonymous function declaration, if you want the component to be rendered, wrap it in an IIFE: `{(() => <App />)()}`. And, of course, you should avoid introducing such unnecessary complexity, so just write  `<App />` here

Comment: @Igorsvee that's what I tried initially - what you're referring to is another attempt that I read about somewhere else.

Comment: Could you add the code where you define `store`? It's most likely that there's an error thrown by either the Provider component or the store variable it's trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

When you saw message "expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function". Actually, Because You did not export function in action or reducer. Please check it carefully.

Cheer!